# Shorten the list of the guild's roles list

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

In my serverinfo command, I have a part where the bot list all the roles in that the guild has. However, when the guild has a very large amount of roles it gives me the error `embed.fields[3].value: Must be 1024 or fewer in length.` I'm not quite sure how the bot will only send the first six roles in the list then rest as `...[number] more roles. v12.2

```
${message.guild.roles.cache.map(r => `${r}`).join(" ").replace("@everyone", " ")}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple, you can use `.array()` method to get an array with all roles and just [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) that array.

"[number] more roles" you can do this just removing 6 of guild roles size

Here is a example:

```
message.guild.roles.cache.array().slice(0,6).map(role => `${role}`).join(" ").replace("@everyone", " ") + (message.guild.roles.cache.size - 6 > 0 ? " and more " + (message.guild.roles.cache.size - 6) + " roles." : "")
```

Worked fine for me.